# XSLT change value of tag with format <ns:foo>

Tags: xslt, transform

i have the following tag and ist value:

```
<dc:source xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"> CH-BAR#E53#1000/893#382#1</dc:source>
```

I want to Change the value (CH-BAR ...) of it using this :

```
<xsl:template match="dc:source/text()">
    <xsl:value-of select="$DocNumber"/>
  </xsl:template>
```

But xslt throws an error because of the `":"` ...

What can I do here?

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot a use namespace prefix without binding to a namespace - for example:

```
<xsl:template match="dc:source/text()" xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/">
    <xsl:value-of select="..."/>
</xsl:template>
```

Normally, you would declare all the required namespaces in the `xsl:stylesheet` root element, thus make them available to all its descendants.

Comment: That was it. Thanks dude